# Does MonoDevelop have multiline edit?

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop, ubuntu-22.04

Can you insert multiple carets/cursors to edit multiple lines simultaneously? [Something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9rtC.png)

This feature is present in most IDEs and text editors nowadays, but I can't find an option to bind it in MonoDevelop `Preferences... -> Environment -> Key Bindings` .

I am using MonoDevelop Version 7.8.4 (build 2) on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second hit [on Google for "MonoDevelop multiline edit"](https://www.google.com/search?q=MonoDevelop+multiline+edit) is [a blog post by Mikayla Hutchinson](https://mhut.ch/journal/2011/03/03/monodevelop-tips-block-selection-mode) that explains how to edit multiple lines at once in MonoDevelop:

> To make a block selection, drag the mouse between the start and end points while holding down the Alt key on Linux [...]
> Alternatively, you can make a normal selection, then use the Edit->Toggle block selection mode to toggle the selection into a block selection with the same start and end points

Comment: This does answer my question. Unfortunately I have just understood that I asked the wrong question. I'll ask another one then.

Comment: No need to ask a new question. Feel free to edit the current one and clarify what you're looking for (unless it's totally different from the original question, then yes, a new question is better.).

Comment: @ikorniie you can take a look at the [how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) help section to get a better feel on how to use this platform.