# Bind multiline edit to a key combination in MonoDevelop

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, monodevelop, ubuntu-22.04

[Multiline edit feature is available in MonoDevelop](https://superuser.com/questions/1741766/does-monodevelop-have-multiline-edit/1741770) but you either need to use a mouse or open a drop-down menu to access it, which are not the most convenient things to do.

Is there a way to bind a key combination to "Add new caret down/up" like in VSCode or numerous other IDEs/text editors?

Binding "Toggle Block Selection Mode" to a key combination is not what I am looking for as it is still not that convenient as simply adding multiple carets using key combinations.

I am using MonoDevelop Version 7.8.4 (build 2) on Ubuntu 22.04